# Filter on parent object attribute in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'd like to be able to filter an object based on an attribute of it's parent:

```
class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :calls
end
```

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Call do
  filter :user
end
```

and have it filter on user.name, rather than present a select of all users. Can this be done?

Answer (score 36):

Denis's solution almost worked for me. I just needed to add the filter type. For example:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Call do
  filter :user_name, :as => :string
end
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Call do
  filter :user_name
end
```

Since ActiveAdmin uses `meta_search` for filters their doc is very helpful: https://github.com/ernie/meta_search

Answer (score 4):

In the next release of ActiveAdmin (I work with 1.0.0.pre) you can use [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) methods. So, let say you have an Article, which belongs_to User.

You will have the following admin/article.rb file

```
ActiveAdmin.register Article do

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      Article.includes(:user)
    end
  end  

  index do      
   column :id
   column :created_at
   column :title
   column("Author", sortable: 'users.first_name') { |item| link_to item.user.full_name, user_path(item.user) }
   actions
  end

  filter :user_first_name_cont, :as => :string
  filter :user_last_name_cont, :as => :string  

end
```

Here, user_first_name_cont is ransack method which filters on associated user first_name and 'cont' means contains.

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested resources from InheritedResource which is used by ActiveAdmin, so your list is automatically filtered by the parent.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  # this is the parent resource
end

ActiveAdmin.register Call do
  belongs_to :user # nested below resource user
end
```

You can then use rake routes to see the new nested routes, generated by ActiveAdmin :) Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it hugely depends on the types of associations you have between your models - it took me hours to figure this out.

Example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :email
end
```

To filter users based on their emails, you do this (don't forget the `as: :string` part as it gives you access to Ransack search methods such as contains and the likes)

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  filter :user_email, :as => :string
end
```