# ActiveAdmin autocomplete for filter on belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, activeadmin

I have a relation like the one described in this item:

[Filter on parent object attribute in ActiveAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909540/filter-on-parent-object-attribute-in-activeadmin)

I have implemented successfully the solution there.  However I would like to implement autocomplete for the text box.

There is an article on using autocomplete in a filter in ActiveAdmin:

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1754

...however this example does not involve a relation and I have not been successful in adapting to my situation.

Here is what I have tried (in my case I am trying to filter on the username field of the user model when viewing the reviews):

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   search_methods :user_username
end
```

ActiveAdmin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Review do

  controller do
    autocomplete :review, :user_username
  end

  filter :user_username, as: :autocomplete,
       url: '/admin/reviews/autocomplete_review_review_user_username',
        label: "Username", required: false
end
```

Route:

```
resources :reviews do
  get :autocomplete_review_user_username, on: :collection
end
```

I have tried several variations on this and the result (when the autocomplete kicks in) usually is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Review with
   id=autocomplete_review_review_user_username):
```

because it is sending and "id" parameter 'autocomplete_review_review_user_username' with the GET request.

I am not sure if the autocomplete is supposed to be tied to the users controller instead but no variation on that worked either.

Comment: It seems the error is in your url parameter to the filter. Instead of supplying a string as a url, you might want to look at the routes with "bundle exec rake routes", and then using a path or url helper. So: url: admin_reviews_autocomplete.....path, look good at step 3 and 4 of the example: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1754

Comment: I did look at the routes in the example.  A dozen times.  I wasn't able to come up with a path that works.  I did try using a path helper...for some reason that didn't work in this context.  But that shouldn't matter.  The path helpers just return a string.  So I used the string shown by the output of 'rake routes'.

Comment: It is fuzzy to me that you should define the route manually while you can define it with the collection_action directive. Another way to provide ease to the user is to use the chosen library and provide the filter as a select with all possible options: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ . Sorry I have not been a lot of help for now. Good luck.

Comment: That would require loading approx. 5000 items into the page.

Comment: autocompletes routes block should be after active admin statement   ActiveAdmin.routes(self)